# How to construct some classes in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, containers, std

I'm working on a class, and I need to have vector of the class. I would like to have objects constructed in place rather than using copy construction. It seems that use of copy construction is inevitable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class MyData {

public:
    int age;
    std::string name;

    MyData(int age, std::string name) : age(age), name(name)
    {
        std::cout << "MyData::MyData(int, std::string)\n";
    }

    MyData(const MyData& myData) : age(myData.age), name(myData.name)
    {
        std::cout << "MyData::MyData(const MyData&)\n";
    }

    MyData(MyData&& myData)
        :age(std::move(myData.age)), name(std::move(myData.name))
    {
        std::cout << "MyData::MyData(MyData&&)\n";
    }

    ~MyData() {
        std::cout << "MyData::~MyData()\n";
    }

};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << "Exec: " #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{

    DEBUG(std::vector<MyData> sb1);
    DEBUG(sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 32, "SJ" }));
    DEBUG(sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 42, "SJ" }));
}
```

The output of the code is as follows :

```
Exec: std::vector<MyData> sb1;
Exec: sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 32, "SJ" });
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
MyData::MyData(MyData&&)
MyData::~MyData()
Exec: sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 42, "SJ" });
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
MyData::MyData(MyData&&)
MyData::MyData(const MyData&)
MyData::~MyData()
MyData::~MyData()
MyData::~MyData()
MyData::~MyData()

C:\Users\XOXOX\source\repos\cpp_stack\x64\Debug\cpp_stack.exe (process 12832) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I'm using C++ 2020 and MSVC.

Comment: `sb1.emplace_back(32, "SJ")`. Your version is equivalent to `push_back`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: works as expected here: https://godbolt.org/z/EzYW13d3j. The one copy you still see is due to the vector resizing and reallocating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First when you write

```
DEBUG(sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 32, "SJ" }));
```

You create a temporary object that gets passed to the `emplaced_back` function. The point of `emplace_back` is that it calls the costructor in-place. So you have to give it the arguments for creating an object, not a temporary object or it will have to use the copy/move constructor.

Second `sb1` is a vector with a capacity of 0. So adding items to it will have to resize and that means copying since the move constructor is not `noexcept`. `std::vector` can not handle exceptions during a resize so it can't risk using your move constructor.

You should reserve the right side to avoid resize.

Comment: Thank you. @463035818_is_not_a_number
I needed to call `sb.reserve(2)` before `emplace(...)`

Comment: nitpick: reserving does not avoid a resize. It avoids reallocation due to increasing the capacity when the vector resizes.

Comment: I was talking about the resize of the memory backing the vector. Not `std::vector::size()` changing.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood what `emplace_back` does.

It takes the parameters you pass and forwards them to the appropriate constructor.

If you do

```
sb1.emplace_back(MyData{ 32, "SJ" });
```

Then the move (or copy) constructor is called. `emplace_back` cannot magically undo the creation of the temporary. If you want to create the element in place then do not pass a temporary `MyData`:

```
sb1.emplace_back(32, "SJ" );
```

This will call the constructor with `int` and `std::string` arguments.

Comment: thank you. it gets better. but it still calls destructor after calling copy constructor . it's not what I need. I want to construct the class in the vector without further overheads. 
my current result is :
```
Exec: std::vector<MyData> sb1;
Exec: sb1.emplace_back(32, "SJ" );
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
Exec: sb1.emplace_back(42, "SJ" );
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
MyData::MyData(const MyData&)
MyData::~MyData()
MyData::~MyData()
MyData::~MyData()```

Comment: @MiladRasouli It doesn't. At least, that code doesn't. If `emplace_back(your, args)` results in the copy constructor being called on the just-constructed element (rather than on previous elements as part of resizing) then you should ask a new question about that, because it's not what C++ does.

Comment: @MiladRasouli why it it not what you need?  The additional copy and element getting destroyed is from the vector resizing. You can avoid it by requesting enough capacity upfront, but you cannot avoid it by doing something on the `emplace` call alone

Comment: I have recently face on a example with `std::piecewise_construct` and `std::forward_as_tuple` . in the example these used for a map. the interesting point is the map doesn't  destruct the class after `emplace`. now I want to do the same but for `vector`

Comment: @MiladRsouli this is doing the same, just that a vector needs to reallocate when increasing its capacity, a map doesnt have capacity. Try `sb1.reserve(2)` just after construction and the reallocation will be gone

Comment: @MiladRasouli actually its already in the other answer. You should perhaps clarify what the desired output is, because it seems you misinterpret where the output is coming from

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
Thank you. `sb.reserve(2)` works well.

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you.